# User specific "resources" with devise and Rails?

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, devise

`user` has many `diary_entries`

`diary_entries` are private to user, so that user can create/edit/see only his own diary_entries.

I haven't implemented this pattern before and trying to figure out how to do this.

First step would be to `before_filter :authenticate_user!`, but this makes `diary_entries` still a "shared" resource among registered users.

In `diary_entries#create` action, we set `@diary_entry.user = current_user`. We then could allow editing/updating only if `@diary_entry.user == current_user`.

Index action simply lists `current_user.diary_entries` instead of all diary entries.

Am I thinking along the right lines here? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to implement permissions. It would make it very easy to restrict a user's access to their own diary_entries. It is also very easy to use. Don't write your own code to handle permissions, otherwise you'll risk compromising privacy and/or security if there are any bugs.

Comment: CanCan seems to do exactly what I suggested, but does it in a centralized and flexible way. Thanks, I'll try it out!

Comment: Glad you found CanCan relevant. I'm biased since I've contributed to the code, but I think it's very awesome.